# How to set environmental variable in systemd service

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I'm working with ROS, which has been installed on my Ubuntu correctly.

To run the ROS, we have to first `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` then execute `roscore`. If I execute `roscore` without `source setup.bash`, the command `roscore` can't be found.

Now, I want to execute the ROS while the system starts up.

I've read this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

It seems that I only need to create a custom service file and put it into `/etc/systemd/system/`. But still I'm not sure what to do because I need to `source setup.bash` to setup some necessary environmental variables before executing `roscore`.

Is it possible to set environmental variables in the service file? For my need, I have to set these environmental variables not only for the execution of `roscore` but also for the whole system.

I have another idea, which is that I set these environmental variables in `/etc/profile` and write a service file only for the command `roscore`, will it work?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Normally `systemd` services have only a limited set of environment variables,
and things in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d` and `bashrc`-related files are not set.

To add environment variables for a `systemd` service you have different possibilities.

The examples as follows assume that `roscore` is at `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore`, since `systemd` services must have the binary or script configured with a full path.

---

One possibility is to use the `Environment` option in your `systemd` service and a simple `systemd` service would be as follows.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/ros.service
[Unit]
Description=ROS Kinetic
After=sshd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="One=1" "Three=3"
Environment="Two=2"
Environment="Four=4"
ExecStart=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

You also can put all the environment variables into a file that can be read with the `EnvironmentFile` option in the `systemd` service.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/ros/roscore.env
One=1
Three=3
Two=2
Four=4


[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/ros.service
[Unit]
Description=ROS Kinetic
After=sshd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/ros/roscore.env
ExecStart=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Another option would be to make a wrapper script for your `ros` binary and call that wrapper script from the `systemd` service. The script needs to be executable.  To ensure that, run

```
chmod 755 /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore.startup
```

after creating that file.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore.startup
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
roscore


[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/ros.service
[Unit]
Description=ROS Kinetic
After=sshd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore.startup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Note that you need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after you have edited the service file to make the changes active. To enable the service on systemboot, you have to enter `systemctl enable ros`.

I am not familiar with the `roscore` binary and it might be necessary to change `Type=` from `simple` (which is the default and normally not needed) to `forking` in the first two examples.

---

For normal logins, you could copy or symlink `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to `/etc/profile.d/ros.sh`, which should be sourced on normal logins.

Comment: One more question: if I set some environmental variables in my service file named `my_own.service`, can other service files containing `Requires=my_own.service` inherit these environmental variables?

Comment: No, the environment won't be inherited.

Comment: if I have ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME insind my .bashrc file what could be a good solution? I think your answer would not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's a terrible idea, why would anyone put .env file inside of the systemd folder. Just put them into /etc/service-name/service.conf or something like that. Systemd folder is preserved for systemd files only for god sake.

Comment: I must agree with @MertÇELEN and updated the path accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can try with this

```
[Unit]
Description=Run command with source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash && /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: We prefer answers that have at least a few sentences of non-code text (and “you can try with this” doesn’t count).  While it may be obvious, you should mention that this solution doesn’t set the ROS-related environment variables for the whole system, which was part of the question.

Comment: @Scott but this is actually an answer :-P