# How can I set and export an environment variable in a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, agetty

after starting `agetty` on my Raspberry Pi in order to attach a VT420 terminal to it, I still have an issue: The shell language must be set to `en_US` and exported by hand right after logging in on the terminal (my version of Raspbian has German locale). Motivation: The terminal does not support UTF-8 characters (and sometimes even stops working when receiving such a character), so I decided to fall back to English locale especially when logging in on the terminal. In all other cases (SSH etc.), UTF-8 is absolutely fine.

I followed the suggestion set forth in [question #455261](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455261/how-to-set-environmental-variable-in-systemd-service) and added the following line to the systemd service file responsible for `agetty`:

```
Environment="LANG=en_US"
```

After a daemon reload and a restart of `agetty`, the login prompt is now in English, but when I start a program (say, `df -h`), its output is still in German and contains UTF-8 characters, causing the already-mentioned problems:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ df -h
Dateisystem           GrÃ¶
```

…whereas the Ã¶ sequence should read as "ö".

On the shell, I would say, `export LANG=en_US`, but I am not sure about how to export an env variable set in a systemd config.

Does anybody know that? Thank you.

Comment: perhaps something in your login is overriding `LANG`?

Comment: Querying `$LANG` in the shell did return `en_US`!

Comment: So it would seem that systemd is successfully setting it? Are we now talking about `df`'s behavior?  Could you show an example of the behavior?

Comment: Well, I have no screenshot from the terminal screen, but see the updated question for how it looked like. Other programs used German locale, too.

Comment: (edit the content into the question; comments are next to useless for output)

Comment: As I've already said: `LANG` is only to be changed when logging in on a serial console. Or do you mean to set `LANG` in `.profile` dependent on `$TERM`?