# Gnome3 Session Startup File

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, startup, gdm3

What is the location of the "Gnome3 Session Startup File".

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with gdm3 as display manager.

I want to export an environment variable (persistent) for GUI (desktop) application.

Also, please tell me the location for system wide gdm3 startup file and user specific gdm3 startup file (for above purpose)?

Comment: If you mean the service file then `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service` which is a symbolic link.

Comment: I want to export an environment variable (persistent) for GUI (desktop) application. Will this work?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455261/ and  https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/